# 'Remember me' is not working in login form. A cookie is getting created, but not showing the value

Tags: php, html

I was trying to implement *remember me* functionality with the cookie method, but it didn’t seem to work. The cookie is getting created in the network tab with the validity I want, but after logout it is not showing on my input tags. Below is my PHP code for the login and login form.

```
<?php
  require('autoload.php');
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

      $email = trim($_POST['login_email']);
      $password = trim($_POST['login_password']);
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` where `user_email` = ? LIMIT 1";
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->get_result();
      $exist = $result->num_rows;
      if($exist == 0){
          echo "invalid credentials";
          exit();
      }else{
          $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
          if (!password_verify($password, $row['user_password'])){
              echo "invalid credentials";
              exit();
          }else{
              if(isset($_POST['remember_me'])){
                 setcookie('email', $email, time() + 60*60*24);
                 setcookie('password', $password, time() + 60*60*24);
              }else{
                 setcookie('email', "");
                 setcookie('password', "");
              }
                  $_SESSION['USERNAME'] = $row['user_name'];
                  $_SESSION['URL'] = $row['url_address'];
                  echo "valid credentials";
                  exit();
              }
          }
      }
   $stmt->close();
  }

  $conn->close();
?>
```

This is my login script and below is my HTML login form.

```
<div class="login-form">

  <form action="" method="post" id="login-form" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="input-container">
      <input type="email" name="login_email" id="login_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email*" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['email'])){ echo $_COOKIE['email'];}?>" required>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-check" id="login_email_correct_mark"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-exclamation" id="login_email_wrong_mark"></i>
      <span class="error_form" id="login_email_error_message"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-container">
      <input type="password" name="login_password" id="login_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password*" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['password'])){ echo $_COOKIE['password'];}?>" required>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-check" id="login_password_correct_mark"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-exclamation" id="login_password_wrong_mark"></i>
      <span class="error_form" id="login_password_error_message"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="remember_me" <?php if(isset($_COOKIE[ 'email'])){?> checked
      <?php }?>> Remember me
      <a href="forgot-password.php">Forgot Password?</a>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="login_submit" id="login_submit" class="submit-btn" value="Login">
  </form>

  <p>Don’t have an Account? <a href="javascript: showRegisterForm();">Register Here</a></p>
  <span id="success-msg">
  </span>
  <span id="failed-msg">
  </span>
</div>
```

The request to the login page is sent by [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery).

Comment: You did not specify the path when setting the cookie, so it will use the path of your current request (the AJAX one) - and the cookie won't be available outside that path.

Comment: I didn't get it , like how to set the path of cookie? can you please elaborated or show an example.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#define_where_cookies_are_sent, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: After reading the docs I think this should work...
setcookie('email',$email,time()+60*60*24,"/");
setcookie('password',$password,time()+60*60*24, "/");

But is it safe to store password and email in cookie?

Comment: @Sameer No, dont store the password in a cookie.

Comment: @user3783243 they what is the good way to use "remember me" functinality?

Comment: @Sameer This seems like a good starting place https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44/how-to-securely-implement-a-remember-me-feature/